# Add bank auth for clients for which information is missing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

```
Clients(Id, LastName, FirstName)

ClientBankAuth(Id, CreationDate, CLientId)
```

I need to find all Clients, that don't have bank auth and add it.

I try to get all data with this query and it returns clients well.

```
 SELECT * FROM clients c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from clientbankauthentications cba where cba.ClientId=c.Id)
```

How I can get all Clients that don't have authentification and add an entry for every client?

Comment: What did you mean by "add it"? Adding to "ClientBankAuth"?

Comment: yes, I need to add an entry to bank auth with clientid and today's date

So for example a client with id 1 don't have auth, so I need to add an entry to the bank auth table with this client id

and same stuff for all clients, that don't have bank auth @KaziMohammadAliNur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select all clients who doesn't have bang auth:

```
select * from clients c
where not exist (select 1 from ClientBankAuth cba where cba.clientid=c.clientid)
```

If your id column is auto generated then to add missing clients to ClientBankAuth

```
    insert into ClientBankAuth(creationdate,clientid)
    select now(),id from clients c
    where not exist (select 1 from ClientBankAuth cba where cba.clientid=c.clientid)
```

Comment: Yes, this is works, but how I can add a bank auth entry for each of the clients that this query returns?

Comment: is your id column auto increament?

Comment: I have revised my answer.